# Alignment bug of Run Code Snippet buttons after approving suggested edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, stack-snippets, diff

I approved a suggested edit [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29706264) by clicking the edit link directly on the post. After approving the edit it seems the "Run code snippet" buttons are vertically aligned in the diff view. Shouldn't there be one button underneath each code fence?

[image: aligned buttons]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 91.0.2 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2021.8.30.40094.

Comment: No repro using FF 78.4.0 on Mac

Comment: @Luuklag as stated in the post, I didn't check in the review queue but by clicking directly on the edit button on the post (the dialogues are different.) This happened after edit approval not before. To reproduce you'd have to take the exact steps mentioned.

Comment: I did @bad_coder. I was the last one to approve the edit.

Comment: This has been reported already, though I’m not sure if the bug has been fixed in the meantime and now there’s a regression: [Doubled stack snippet buttons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346241/4642212). I believe it may be caused by an action which causes a request (such as approving an edit suggestion) while some scripts aren’t fully loaded, e.g. when the internet connection is slow.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that post is interesting because it doesn't mention suggested edits but user edits. It also doesn't link to a post where it happened.